# How to create a slide menu on a Tab Bar Button touch

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, slidingmenu

I made a a tab bar view controller using storyboard. I thought it would be nice to implement a sliding menu when a tab bar button is tapped. How do I accomplish this?

My Storyboard: [image]

Answer (score 0):

First, up all Apple always recommends using tab bar instead of side menu but still if you want to make side menu u can do it by using [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) or [SwrevealviewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

Comment: Yes I understand that. I want to keep my tab bar, but I want one of the tab bar buttons to open up a side menu. I don't like how it automatically creates a more tab that doesn't look attractive.